# Data from h2 imported into img title attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I need to use the data from an H2 element and plug that into the title attribute of an image on the page. I've been trying to use the jQuery data function, but it's failed. Know of a better way to solve this?

Comment: Show us what you have tried and we can help you from there.

Comment: This is what I originally tried:

`$("h2").ready(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    $('img').attr("title", $this.text());
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by data you mean the content of the h2 then this should do

```
$(function () {
  $("img").attr("title", $("h2").text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple:

```
$(function () {
  $("img#toId").attr("title", $("h2#fromId").data("something"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What data from the h2? The text inside of the tags? The `.text` method will give you the contents of the tag, and you can set the title on the image using the `.attr` method.

`$("#myimage").attr("title", $("#myh2").text());`

If it's an actual data attribute on the h2, then you can use the `.data` method to pull it out. Assuming an h2 like: `<h2 id="myh2" data-mydata="foobar">Hey you guys!</h2>` you can do:

`$("#myimage").attr('title', $("#myh2").data('mydata'));`

Comment: .html() will return an HTML string which might break the title attribute (e.g. title="<span id="foo">bla</span>"), using .text() is safer as it strips out tags.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion. I was referring to the text inside of the H2.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the jquery data, rather than the text of the h2, you could do this:

html:

```
<h2 data-imgTitle="Image Title">Header Content</h2>
```

javascript:

```
$(function () {
  $("img").attr("title", $("h2").data("imgTitle"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually trying to take that "Header Content" text and move it into the title attribute of the image.